# Two Imports with same name conflicts

Tags: android, import

I am trying to use apphance for beta testing.

I need to

```
import com.apphance.android.common.Configuration;
```

but I am already using

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
```

which conflicts with the other import. How do I resolve it?

Comment: you don't need to use import, use fully qualified class name for one of Configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this import:

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
```

and like selvin says use Fully Qualified Class Name for the second `Configuration` class.

```
com.apphance.android.common.Configuration configuration = new Configuration...
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't import one of them.

When referring to 2 classes that have the same name, only one can be imported. The second one needs to be referred to by it's fully qualified name, like so:

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
[...]
// This is android.content.res.Configuration
Configuration config = ...;
// This is com.apphance.android.common.Configuration
com.apphance.android.common.Configuration conf = ...;
```